# How to install Kdenlive 15.04 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, 15.04, kdenlive

How can I install **Kdenlive 15.04** on Ubuntu 14.04?

Kdenlive recommends to use this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~sunab/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-release

But it does not have the latest version.

How do I get the latest version? Do I need to install Kubuntu 15.04 to use the newest version or will the newest version be available for Ubuntu 14.04 some day?

Comment: As told in https://kdenlive.org : ' Since we are now based on Qt5/KF5, you NEED KDE Frameworks 5 to run Kdenlive.'. The 14.04 only has the KDE4.

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible, Install 15.10 and

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release
```

set password and follow instructions, next add

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

yo obtain at this time kdenlive 15.12.1