# Screen recording software

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast, desktop-recording

I want to be able to reliably record videos for a YouTube channel, however the software I've tried all has individual flaws.
The programs I've tried are:

- SimpleScreenRecorder (flaw being that the audio begins to echo after a while when recording)
- Kazam (flaw being the computer crashing whilst processing very long recordings)
- OBS (flaw being spontaneous freezing of whole computer system)
- RecordMyDesktop (flaw being that I have 2 monitors so its difficult to get the recording space right)

Are there any reliable alternatives?

Comment: Still curious, did you try?

Comment: @JacobVlijm not yet, i get back to my computer tomorrow so ill try then

Comment: @JacobVlijm vokoscreen crashes with 'illegal instruction' error on my setup

Comment: Huh?? What is your Ubuntu version? Unity 14.04/15.10/16.04 works fine here.

Comment: @JacobVlijm 14.04. It downloaded an old version but qmake is giving me grief trying to install vokoscreen 2.4.0

Comment: I just instalped it from the repos...

Comment: @JacobVlijm Okay i managed to get a more up to date copy by downloading the deb. It seems pretty stable and has all the functions i want. Will test it properly soonish as soon as i get the time for an hours playing with my friend. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Thanks for mentioning, curious how it will survive :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record my screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-record-my-screen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Vokoscreen](http://www.kohaupt-online.de/hp/) works remarkably well on my system. The [screencast in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/684642/72216) was made with it.

[image]

It has a number of options, a.o. to record a section of the screen, the whole screen, sound options and so on.

You'll have to see if it works in your situation for your specific requirements though.

Vokoscreen is in the repos.

Comment: okay thank you. will try this as soon as i get back to my computer! how can i download this through command line? i presume apt-get install vokoscreen?

Comment: @Jelly if you make it *sudo* `apt-get install vokoscreen` it should work.

Comment: Crashes with 'Illegal Instruction'. It downloaded version 1.9.0 though and i can't figure how to get the updated version

Comment: Nevermind: managed to get a later version which seems more stable. Will test it properly soonish

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [**kdenlive**](https://kdenlive.org/) it has an editor and plugin, I tried all you mentioned but all of them are not comparable with it, available by default on  **16.04 Software Center** you can see more help [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626529/how-to-install-kdenlive-15-04-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install on **14.04** it's almost equivalent to **[camtasia studio](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html)** on ubuntu

[image]