# How can i record screen and also write with pen mark

Tags: x121e

I want to know how can I write in on screen in Ubuntu with screen recording also and voice recording also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen recording software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773740/screen-recording-software)

Answer (score 0):

If you want record the screen and your voice try use Kazam

`sudo apt install kazam`

Comment: Kazam doesn't have the write with pen mark feature.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not specify a desktop environment, I am providing an answer suited to the default Ubuntu Desktop, which uses Gnome Shell.

Gnome Shell includes build in [screencast capabilities](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en). Still, it does not record audio, and you are probably better of using one of the possible dedicated applications which you will find when searching for "screencast" in the Ubuntu software store. "SimpleScreenRecorder" and "Kazam" are two well know applications, but the king of screencasting software is OBS studio, although with its power comes a slightly steeper learning curve.

To annotate the screen in Gnome Shell/Ubuntu desktop, you can use an excellent Gnome Shell extension. The extension "[Draw On You Screen](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1683/draw-on-you-screen/)" by abakkk is officially supported by the Ubuntu developpers, and can be installed from the Software Center, or using the terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-draw-on-your-screen
```

Another option to draw on the screen that works independently of the desktop environment is Gromit, available from the software center as a regular or as a Snap package.